# Is there a simple ORM for .Net like Vici CoolStorage?

Tags: .net, orm, coolstorage

I really like Vici CoolStorage because it is very simple to use and work with MySQL. I've tried NHibernate but I just don't get it. Does anyone know or can you suggest a .Net ORM that is simple and light because it look like Vici CoolStorage is dead.

Comment: Have you tried Entity Framework 4?

Comment: If the answers given so far don't help, perhaps you can add some description to your question - for those not familiar with CoolStorage, what features does it have that you're specifically looking for?

Comment: Why do you think it's dead? A new version has just been released with support for Windows Phone as well as .NET

Answer (score 2):

Try Linq to SQL and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something simpler for .NET, look into some of the Micro ORMs, like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), or [ORMLite](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite).